# Is this a valid proof for uniform continuity of $\frac{x^2}{x+1}$?

Tags: proof-verification, continuity

I want to prove that $f(x)=\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ is uniformly continuous on $[0, \infty). $

Let $y=x+\delta>x$

$$\implies \lvert f(x)-f(y) \rvert=\lvert f(x)-f(x+\delta) \rvert= \vert{\frac{x^2}{x+1}-\frac{(x+\delta)^2}{x+\delta+1}}\lvert$$

since $\frac{x^2}{x+1}$ is always increasing on $[0, \infty)$ it follows that $f(x+\delta)>f(x)$ $$\implies-\left(-\frac{(x+\delta)^2}{x+\delta+1}+\frac{x^2}{x+1}\right)=\frac{(x+\delta)^2}{x+\delta+1}-\frac{x^2}{x+1} \\<\frac{(x+\delta)^2}{x+1}-\frac{x^2}{x+1} \color{red}{<}\frac{(x+\delta)^2}{\color{red}{x+\delta}}-\frac{x^2}{x+1}$$

since $\frac{x^2}{x+1}<x$

$$\implies \frac{(x+\delta)^2}{x+\delta}-\frac{x^2}{x+1}<x+\delta-x=\delta \\\implies \text{choose } \delta=\epsilon \\ \implies\lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert<\epsilon$$

The $\color{red}{\text{red}}$ part ist what I am unsure about. This inequality basically only works when $\delta<1$ and I am not sure if it must be true for all deltas? (I am not really looking for alternate ways to prove it because I kind of want to figure it out by myself. I am only unsure about the red part. If it is wrong and my proof doesn't make sense I'll just give it another go)

Comment: The red part is fine if you restrict $\delta < 1$ which is totally acceptable; otherwise, in the step before the red part, why did you drop the $\delta$ from the denominator in the first place? You could just have easily have used $$\frac{(x+\delta)^2}{x+\delta + 1} < \frac{(x+\delta)^2}{x + \delta}.$$ I.e., drop the $1$ from the denominator, not the $\delta$.

As an aside, an easy fact to quote here: bounded derivative implies uniform continuity (actually Lipschitz continuity). If the derivative is bounded by $L$, take $\delta = \epsilon / L$ by the mean value theorem. (Here $L =1$).

Comment: @User8128 I think I "tunnel-visioned" when adding and subtracting the $\delta$. I will take a look at lipschitz ocntinuity and the bounded derivative "test" you mentioned. Seems like a much quicker and more usefult test. Thank you very much for your help!